# Using a polymorphic function to extract an object from Options

Tags: scala, shapeless

The shapeless documentation explains how to use polymorphic functions to make a function that maps objects in one kind of container to another, but what about when you want to unpack things from their container?

I have a HList of Options

```
val options = Some(1) :: Some("A") :: Some(3.5) :: HNil
```

I want a polymorphic function that can extract the contents of each of the Options.

```
// This is incorrect:
object uuu extends (Option ~> Any) {
  def apply[T](l:Option[T]):T = {
    l.get
  }
}
```

If this function was correct, I'd want the following behavior:

```
options.map(uuu) // I want: 1 :: "A" :: 3.5 :: HNil
```

How can I correct this so that my polymorphic function actually works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The first is that the static type of your hlist has `Some` in it instead of `Option`, so the `Mapper` evidence that you need to prove that `uuu` can be mapped over `options` won't be found. The nicest way to fix this is to define a smart `Some` constructor that returns an `Option`:

```
def some[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)

val options = some(1) :: some("A") :: some(3.5) :: HNil
```

You could also add type annotations to your original `options`, or change `uuu` to work with `Some` instead of `Option` (which would be safer, but presumably less useful for whatever it is you're aiming to do).

Now your code compiles and does *something*, but only because of the somewhat bizarre fact that `Any` is kind-polymorphic in Scala. In general when you have `F ~> G`, both `F` and `G` have to be type constructors that take a single type parameter—e.g. `Option ~> List`. `Any` doesn't take a type parameter, and yet it works, because of this weird fact about the Scala language (that `Any`, together with `Nothing`, is kind-polymorphic and will fit any slot where you need a type, a type constructor with one parameter, a type constructor with a dozen parameters, etc.).

So it compiles, but it's pretty useless, since it returns an `Any :: Any :: Any :: HNil`. You can fix this by replacing the `Any` in the natural transformation with `shapeless.Id`:

```
import shapeless._, shapeless.poly.~>

def some[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)

val options = some(1) :: some("A") :: some(3.5) :: HNil

object uuu extends (Option ~> Id) {
  def apply[T](l: Option[T]): T = l.get
}

options.map(uuu)
```

`Id` is defined as `type Id[+T] = T`—i.e., it's the identity type constructor that gives you the unwrapped type.

This version both compiles and gives you back a usefully-typed result, but it's still not really safe, since if you map over an `hlist` with elements that are `None` (at runtime), you'll get a `NoSuchElementException`. There's not really any way around this apart from changing `Option ~> Id` to `Some ~> Id`, somehow providing default values, etc., all of which change the nature of the operation pretty dramatically.

Comment: Could you please explain, `Any is kind-polymorphic in Scala`, Travis?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Well, that paragraph explains the basics. For something more concrete, define `def foo[F[_, _, _]](f: F[Int, Int, Int]) = f` and try `foo[Any](1)`.